# electromagnetics as a form of Gravity

Tags: artificial-gravity

Wondering if anyone has ideas about creating an electromagnetic field in the Floor of an exercise room combined with clothing that is laced with metal strands.  the intensity could be adjusted to individual needs.  Thoughts??

Comment: This question does not fit to space exploration, physics would fit better.

Comment: @Uwe the OP's original question did not ask about generating real gravity with EM field. I've made a small edit to make it clearer they'd like to know if EM forces have been considered as an alternate form of "artificial gravity."

Comment: see also https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9641/could-magnetic-boots-be-used-to-simulate-the-effects-of-gravity-for-asteroid-s

Comment: no evidence @uhoh's question matched the OP's intent as he claims. It's a significantly different question in that form.

Comment: @DouglasWoodbury welcome to Space! If you click "edited" to the left of your name under the question, you can see the edit history. There's a draft of changes I'd made that suggest one way your question can be improved. Right now your question has been closed, possibly some of those thoughts can help you reformulate your question, and then it may be reopened.

Comment: Related electromagnetic replacement for gravity questions: [Are magnetic boots in space practical?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12725/12102) and also [Could magnetic “boots” be used to simulate the effects of gravity for asteroid ships?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9641/12102)

Comment: I've just asked [Proposed methods to use electromagnetic force to replace gravity beyond boots?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34010/12102)