# Proposed methods to use electromagnetic force to replace gravity beyond boots?

Tags: astronauts, artificial-gravity, astronaut-lifestyle, reduced-gravity-sports

I have been wondering if there have been any serious proposed methods to try to recover some functions of gravity with electromagnetic forces for astronauts in space.

Fields generated in the floor of an exercise room, hallway, or work area, combined with clothing laced with metal strands, coils, or magnetic materials perhaps.

The intensity could be adjusted to individual needs.

While the questions below ask about magnetic boots for attachment, I'm asking here about providing some force to additional locations on a person to provide some additional things that real or artificial gravity can provide, examples might include maintenance of muscle tone, not having to hook your arms into something to keep them from floating up and getting in the way, aspects of sports, exercise, yoga, etc.

---

- [Are magnetic boots in space practical?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12725/12102)
- [Could magnetic “boots” be used to simulate the effects of gravity for asteroid ships?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9641/12102)

Comment: I haven't asked if this is possible or how it would be done. I've asked "...if there have been any serious proposed methods to try to recover some functions of gravity with electromagnetic forces for astronauts in space." That seems absolutely on-topic here and would be migrated here if asked in Physics SE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could magnetic "boots" be used to simulate the effects of gravity for asteroid ships?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9641/could-magnetic-boots-be-used-to-simulate-the-effects-of-gravity-for-asteroid-s)

Comment: VTC because the answers to "Could magnetic “boots” be used to simulate the effects of gravity for asteroid ships?" also apply to other objects that use electromagnetic force.

Comment: @Hobbes I haven't asked if this is possible or how it would be done. I've asked "...if there have been any serious proposed methods to try to recover some functions of gravity with electromagnetic forces for astronauts in space." I see zero links to any serious proposed methods, only users providing their own opinions. This is a different question. Somebody else **incorrectly added** the `design-alternative` tag, I am removing it now.

Comment: @Hobbes your physics arguments there are weak, one would not use a single dipole magnet under the floor. You've chosen the *worst possible implementation* to try to hand-wave the problem away. That's not good enough to be sure that nobody has looked into this, and I think you will find that people have indeed looked into this. So this is not a good close reason. Of course *quickly closing the question* will block people from posting answers that could show that there are. Why not leave it open and find out?

Comment: @uhoh good point on the tag.

Comment: It's late and I can't write the meta question *Are "would this work" and "has this been studied" the same thing?* but I feel that the answer is no, they are different and should be treated differently. "I don't think it could work, therefore nobody could have ever proposed or studied it" is probably not the best rationalization for a close vote.

Comment: All right, I'm removing comments musing that it wouldn't work. That's not the point of the question, and if the intention is to provide a thorough examination of why the OP will not find any such proposals due to known limitations, the comment space is not for that.

Comment: Some magnetic bearing use gravity to keep centered on an object. These types of bearings would need a counter magnetic set to replace the missing gravity. A levitron https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21284/can-a-neutrally-bouyant-helium-balloon-be-suspended-in-air-using-magnet-entrapme also works with gravity and another base magnetic would be needed to work in space.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/liquid-shield-for-spacecraft  I am thinking about little magnetic bearing that rotates on the heat shield on a solar probe to distribute heat.